# Wicket form makes entire page disappear

Tags: forms, jetty, wicket, embedded-jetty

A couple of years ago I was moderately proficient in Wicket. Today I picked it up again at the latest version, 6.12.0. I'm using it in an embedded Jetty server. I managed to configure everything and get a "Hello World" page working.

But here's the odd thing: the minute I add a form, the entire page disappears! Let's say I have:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>blah</p>
<p><label>Upload File:</label> <input wicket:id="fileUpload"
    type="file" size="40" /><br /> <input wicket:id="uploadButton"
    type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
```

That works fine. Then I add:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>blah</p>
<form wicket:id="form">...</form>
```

Suddenly the page is blank! The response code is still `200 OK`, but there is no content. Here's what comes back:

```
Date: Tue, 19 Nov 2013 01:32:48 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(9.1.0.v20131115)

200 OK
```

Yes, when I add the form, I make sure the components on the form (e.g. the buttons) are now programmatically added to the form instead of the page:

```
final Form form=new Form("form");
form.add(new FileUploadField("fileUpload"));
form.add(new Button("uploadButton"));
add(form);
```

Comment: It looks well, probably there could be anything other that's wrong. Could you post the full code and markup or make a link to it? Is there anything in log (jetty, wicket), enable wicket trace logging (set logger.org.apache.wicket=trace).

Comment: Martin, where do I set the `logger.org.apache.wicket` property? Is it a system property? Is it an init param? Is it a log4j property? I searched but could find no documentation. It's not in the PDF Users's Guide. It's not in _Wicket in Action_.

Answer (score 0):

My Jetty configuration had disabled sessions. I didn't see the exception (which was clear about the problem) because I hadn't configured log4j for the project. After changing `NO_SESSIONS` to `SESSIONS` forms seem to work fine:

```
final ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
```